# The basic memory address question about array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice, python-internals

Doing some basic experiments about Python array slicing. Why the same level has the same `id`(address), but the array value is different. Is the the mechanism of Python slicing, or it just how `id()` works?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
def test2(a, level):
    if not a: return
    mid = len(a) // 2
    print(level, a, id(a))

    if len(a) > 1:
        test2(a[:mid], level + 1)
        test2(a[mid:], level + 1)
test2(a, 0)


## Result:
# 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 4565360520
# 1 [1, 2, 3] 4565360456
# 2 [1] 4566307656
# 2 [2, 3] 4566307656
# 3 [2] 4566307592
# 3 [3] 4566307592
# 1 [4, 5, 6] 4565360456
# 2 [4] 4566307656
# 2 [5, 6] 4566307656
# 3 [5] 4566307592
# 3 [6] 4566307592
## Same level has same id??
```

Then when I append the `[level, a, id(a)]` in to a stack then print it out.
The same level has different id now. No matter when I print it out in the function, or store in the stack, then print it out one by one.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
stack = []
def test2(a, level):
    if not a: return
    mid = len(a) // 2
    print(level, a, id(a))
    stack.append([level, a, id(a)])
    if len(a) > 1:
        test2(a[:mid], level + 1)
        test2(a[mid:], level + 1)
test2(a, 0)

print("-----------------")
stack = sorted(stack)
for i in stack:
    print(i)

'''
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 4393918344
1 [1, 2, 3] 4394865352
2 [1] 4394510088
2 [2, 3] 4394865608
3 [2] 4394867592
3 [3] 4394867656
1 [4, 5, 6] 4394867912
2 [4] 4394868040
2 [5, 6] 4394868168
3 [5] 4394867720
3 [6] 4394868360
-----------------
[0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4393918344]
[1, [1, 2, 3], 4394865352]
[1, [4, 5, 6], 4394867912]
[2, [1], 4394510088]
[2, [2, 3], 4394865608]
[2, [4], 4394868040]
[2, [5, 6], 4394868168]
[3, [2], 4394867592]
[3, [3], 4394867656]
[3, [5], 4394867720]
[3, [6], 4394868360]
'''
```

Comment: You're using CPython, right? `id()` is implementation-specific.

Comment: In the version of your code where you don't save all of the slices, the two slices at the same level *don't exist in memory at the same time* (`a[:mid]` goes out of scope and is garbage-collected before `a[mid:]` comes into existence).  It's therefore entirely possible (although certainly not guaranteed) that the first one's ID gets reused for the second one.

Comment: @jason Could you post that as an answer please? I would upvote. The only thing I could think to add is a quote from the documentation where it says the id number isn't guaranteed to be anything in particular.

Comment: whoops - got my negations mixed up in my previous comment. ID values are only guaranteed to be distinct for objects with *overlapping* lifetimes; two objects with *non-overlapping* lifetimes may share an ID.